# Bind SIGTERM to a member function

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to create a simple class to signals handling (just for study) with **std::bind**. However, I could not compile this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <csignal>
using namespace std;

class SignalHandler
{   
public:

    void handler(int value)
    {
        cout << value << endl;
    }

    SignalHandler()
    {
        auto callback = std::bind(&SignalHandler::handler, this, std::placeholders::_1);

        sighandler_t ret = std::signal(SIGTERM, callback);
        if (SIG_ERR == ret) {
            throw;
        }
    }

};

int main() {

    SignalHandler handler;

    raise(SIGTERM);

    return 0;
}
```

(GCC) Compiler exit:
prog.cpp: In constructor 'SignalHandler::SignalHandler()':
prog.cpp:21:51: error: cannot convert 'std::_Bind(SignalHandler*, std::_Placeholder<1>)>' to '__sighandler_t {aka void (*)(int)}' for argument '2' to 'void (* signal(int, __sighandler_t))(int)'
   sighandler_t ret = std::signal(SIGTERM, callback);

Comment: `std::signal` is from C. C doesn't know functors but functions. So `std::signal` expects a function pointer. So non-global state for your handler isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *static* methods to handle SIGTERM, et al.  I've done that before.  `static` was the key to get signatures to match.